# __dopostback not working as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, updatepanel

**Scenario 1 (That Works)**
This is a POC i created.
I have a script manager, a html textbox, an ASP.NET button, an updatepanel with async trigger set for Click event of above mentioned button. For html textbox i have, `onkeyup='__doPostBack('<%=ASPBUTTON.ClientID%>','')`. AND IT WORKS, the Click event of button is hit, and updatepanel is updated asynchronously.

**Scenario 2 (It's not working)**
The only difference with my actual codebase is that i have a JQUERY FILAMENTGROUP datetimepicker whose onchange event is being used instead of html textbox's onchange. Further, here my page uses a master page. Now, my problem is that when onchange event for datetimepicker fires, the request goes server side, but BUTTON click event is not getting fired.

Some more details,
I want to update the updatepanel automatically on datetimepicker selection. So, the button would be actually hidden through css (display:none).

Button id - btnDateRangeCallback

Datetimepicker Textbox (non ASP control) - dateRange

```
        onChange: function() {__doPostBack('<%=btnDateRangeCallback.ClientID%>',   $('#dateRange').val());}
```

**[Please remember i said it works in case of my simplistic POC, while in my actual codebase i am using a masterpage to inherit from, and so all these controls are placed in a contentplaceholder. Furthermore, postback is happening, and i can see _EVENTTARGET and _EVENTARGUMENT being sent correctly if i break at Page_Load]**

Please help.

To put it more simply,
After postback, when i break at Page_Load, i see the Request.Form contents as,
ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24SMgr1=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24SMgr1%7cctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDateRangeCallback
&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDateRangeCallback
&_*EVENTARGUMENT=5%2f3%2f2011+-+6%2f2%2f2011
&*_VIEWSTATE=%2fwEPDwULLTE3NDY5NDIwMDRkZIuTqMNNsFHlRYhjpKaUCaCXj42h
&_*EVENTVALIDATION=%2fwEWAgLBx52kBALP6Ln6DdkkwE%2frVIKQzKE1L0k4QhIc768w
&*_ASYNCPOST=true&

Why is not Click event for btnDateRangeCallback hitting???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the UniqueID instead: `__doPostBack('<%=btnDateRangeCallback.UniqueID %>', ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to this:

```
setTimeout(function () { __doPostBack('btnSave', '') }, 500);
```

Use "btnSave Id". It will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just click the button?

```
onchange="$('#<%= ASPBUTTON.ClientID %>').click()"
```

(Ideally, don't use inline event handlers either...)

If that's no good for you, you could work around it using `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` (see [this article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx) for a guide).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is **because** it is in a content place holder.

The first parameter of `__doPostBack` is used server side, client side it can be anything.  So `__doPostBack` is called and submits as desired, but on the server, the first parameter's value is used to find the control that will handle the events.  It is used to find the control with the matching UniqueId.

When not in a NamingContainer, UniqueID and ClientID are the same, inside a NamingContainer the ClientId is constructed using underscores (_) and the UniqueId is constructed using dollar signs ($).

Since the value that the server receives in this case doesn't allow it to find a control, it doesn't know what event to fire, and so doesn't fire any, despite registering as a post back and **appearing** to having an "__EVENTTARGET" that would allow it to find the control.

ClientId will SOMETIMES work when NOT on a MasterPage, in particular it will work just so long as the control is not inside a `NamingContainer`.  The reason why it won't ever work inside a master page, is that the master page always has a naming container.