# asp.net button Postback using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm in need of doing a post back for an asp.net button inside jQuery modal dialog. The markup I have is something like this

```
 <div id="content">
        <h1>
            Join Our Community</h1>`enter code here`
        <hr />
       Some Context..
        <br />
        <br />
         Some Context..
        <hr />
        <br />
        <!-- Modal Dialog -->
        <a id="tos" href="#serviceterms" title="You must agree with our tems of service.">Click
            HERE to Agree to our Terms </a>
        <div style="display: none">
            <div id="serviceterms" style="width: 440px; height: 250px; overflow: auto;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                <br />
                <br />
       Some Context..
                <br />
                <br />
                <hr />
                <input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="ToS_Agree()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="button" value="No" onclick="ToS_NotAgree()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" Enabled="False" ClientIDMode="Static"
            OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="LabelResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

In the jQuery Section, the code is something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#tos").fancybox({
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'modal': 'true',enter code here
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none'
    });
});

function ToS_Agree() {
    $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    __doPostBack('<%# HiddenButton.ClientID %>', '')

}

function ToS_NotAgree() {
    $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.fancybox.close();
}
```

**Problem:** When I hit the yes button in the modal dialog, it is posting back correctly. But it directs me to the page_load event body and doesn't go to Button1_Click body. Please help me here. I personally believe that there must be a way to get my desired event body using jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213580/dopostback-not-working-as-expected/6214387

Answer (score 3):

An expression with the `#` sign is a data-binding expression. It will only evaluate `DataBind()` is called. Use the `=` sign:

```
__doPostBack('<%= HiddenButton.UniqueID %>', '')
```

Comment: This is common mistake to use control's `ClientID` for `__doPostBack` function parameter. Use `UniqueID` property instead and you'll save a lot of time of debugging.

Comment: thanks for your concern :) this is helpful  plz also  help me in the actual problem i have posted ..thanks in Advance

Comment: the problem is, when i hit the Yes Button i  go inside Page_load Function body but after that it doesn't get me to my OnLCick Event .. like other asp.net  controls do on postabck..

Comment: do u mean unique id like __doPostBack('<%= HiddenButton.UniqueID %>', '') (i m currently doing in this way) ? or is there any other way to use unique id .

Comment: Yes I mean this. BTW, how do you make your button hidden?

Comment: i did use the unique Id , but it didn't work. it let me to go to page_load event. not to the button click event. Sorry for my naming convention, i didn't hide this button just named it hidden :)

Comment: Can you use tracing to see the page life cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
__doPostBack('<%# HiddenButton.ClientID %>', '')
```

Do this:

```
$("#<%=HiddenButton.ClientID%>").click();
```

It will make the click button clicked and fire your server-side event.

Comment: thanks for your replay. :) well this solution doesn't work for me..  and there are posts according to which .click() is not compatible with all browsers